# IntelliJ IDEA back/forward with mouse

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to move back/forward between editor tabs, using the two additional ("virtual") mouse buttons I have ([RAZER DEATHADDER BLACK](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-mice/razer-deathadder-black/)).

In Eclipse, it's possible by default.

In IDEA, I go to `File`->`Settings`->`Keymap`->`Main menu`->`Window`->`Editor Tabs`.
There, I have `Select Next Tab` with the default `Alt+Right` shortcut.

Then, I open the `Add Mouse Shortcut`.
In that dialog, I try to assign the `back` button of my mouse but without success. **It doesn't react at all.**

Anyway, googling a bit, I've found [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76787) thread. I quote `Alexey Gopachenko` which seems to be an employee of IntelliJ:

> As stated above - we can't support buttons if JDK on your platform
> does not support them - and obviously it does not.

Anyway, that is totally wrong. My platform does support these keys - I actually work with them, on the same platform, on Eclipse and any other app, so it's IDEA who ignores them.

I'd appreciate a solution - how do I assign these back/forward mouse buttons?

**UPDATE #1**
I've found out that **IDEA uses its own JAVA distribution** (`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.4\jre` on Windows 7), instead of the system's one - WHY?!
I'm almost SURE that is the reason I cannot use extended mouse buttons.
I've tried to trick IDEA by creating a custom Windows shortcut. Didn't work. I've also tried to create a SYMLINK in windows to my other, system-wide JRE distribution. Didn't work as well.
If someone come up with an idea on how to make it work with the system's JRE instead of its own - I think that'd solve the issue.

**UPDATE #2**
The above update #1 is not the issue.

Comment: I tried it on IDEA v11 & v12.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enter-mouse-shortcut-dialog.html

Comment: Interestingly, I have the same mouse and the back/forward buttons seems to work when I'm remote logging into my workstation but it doesn't work when I'm physically at my workstation.

Comment: I have the 2 of the same mouse using latest android studio on my home pc and latest intellij on my work pc, back/forward works on my work pc but not the home pc. It is so frustrating! Ive tried mapping using the HP Omen software, tried mapping using IntelliJ, none works

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem under OS X El Capitan. I just tried to add a new Keyboard-Shortcut and pressed than the Button 4 on the mouse and this worked.

[image: view Screenshot]

Comment: Argh! Why would they map that button to the keyboard!? Oh well, it works - nice find!

Comment: Double Argh! Except by using that shortcut, you can't move your cursor to the forward/end of a line, so that's not ideal.

Comment: Actually better solution is to use software to map the mouse buttons to the existing navigational keystrokes Cmd + [ and Cmd + ]. I have a logitech mouse so I use Logitech Control Center. If on OSX, BetterTouchTool is another good app that that can probalby do it for any mouse.

Answer (score 6):

### Update - Fixed Natively in IntelliJ IDEA

While OP had trouble with this, this issue seems to have been fixed according to this issue [Make back/forward mouse buttons go to the previous/next edit place in editor](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76787/Make-back-forward-mouse-buttons-go-to-the-previous-next-edit-place-in-editor).  So it's much easier going forward to use the native way in IntelliJ IDEA to bind mouse clicks to keyboard shortcuts.

1. Locate the shortcut you'd like to add a binding for in the `Settings` > `Keymap`
2. Right click and Select `Add Mouse Shortcut`

   [image: Add mouse Shortcut context menu]
3. Which should pull up this window which accept any mouse input clicks

   [image: Mouse shortcut menu]
4. Click the back button or whatever you'd like on your mouse, and click OK

   [image: Back button registered]
5. The shortcut should now appear in the keymap bindings

   [image: keymap bindings]
6. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> before closing the settings dialog! And that's it!

Comment: Don't forget to click `Apply` at the bottom right to save the shortcut after adding.

Comment: @cachius - good catch - thanks!  Added to post.  I definitely had to do this twice when I was doing it the first time because I just closed out of the settings dialog.  Breaks my brain a little that these settings aren't auto saved as you work on them.

Answer (score 3):

`Back`/`Forward` mouse shortcuts work fine for me with Razer Mamba mouse, for example **Back** action is assigned to **Button4 Click** and I can confirm that it is recognized in this dialog when I click on the Click Pad area:

[image: mouse shortcut]

If it doesn't work with your mouse for some reason, you can try to workaround the problem using the Razer Configurator macro or key assignments:

[image: razer]

Use the assigned key in IDEA keymap settings instead of the mouse shortcut.

---

Note that Eclipse is SWT based while IDEA is Swing based, so mouse event management is completely different. If JDK cannot recognize your device button clicks, it will not work in any Java Swing applications (NetBeans, JEdit, etc). In some cases [running IDEA under a more recent JDK version](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/running-mustang/) may help (if support for your device was added in the newer JDK release).

Comment: First THANK YOU for trying! I use my mouse using the Windows 7 default supplied driver. I'll try tomorrow using it with the mouse's driver, hope it works. And, I have the very latest JDK - as I've said - thee two mouse buttons work on Eclipse, which is JDK based too.

Comment: Note that IDEA on Windows in bundled with it's own JDK in `jre` directory, you can override it by setting `IDEA_JDK` environment variable. Also note that Eclipse is SWT based, so you should compare only with Swing applications like mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yea, I've disabled the bundled JRE, it uses my system-wide JDK version. Unfortunately the Razer driver (and its software) did not fix the problem. I don't understand what is going on, is there any special JDK version that I should be using? ... Seems like I've stepped over java's toe heh

Comment: LOL, few seconds after I wrote the above comment I realized I did not really try all your methods (keyboard key assignment). I'll be back with a report about it tomorrow :) However, now that I think about it, if I assign another key to it - won't it make issues with other programs? I'll try anyway..

Comment: For me it works without any mappings and with both JDK 1.6 and 1.7 versions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the exact same thing suddenly.
I realized my most recent change was to start using idea64.exe rather than idea.exe.
I switched back, and my mouse buttons are working fine again.
So, while this is not a complete answer, it seems as if it has something to do with the 64-bit version.

Comment: Having the same problem with the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

If the Razer driver's button mapping feature doesn't allow different mappings for a particular program, you can just assign the buttons to the mouse button number choices (mouse button 4 / mouse button 5) and then install a third party app that does support mappings for particular programs, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/562972/how-to-map-bind-mouse-button-as-keyboard-button-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

This question helped me although I have a Logitech Marathon Mouse M705, so I thought that I would share the solution in case other Logitech owners was in search for this.

I have a similar problem with a Logitech mouse and idea64.exe

Fortunately their SetPoint software allows for program specific settings.
This setting will have to be deleted and then reconfigured whenever you update IntelliJ and get a new idea64.exe :-)

[image: Application specific settings for Logitech mouse]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this little tutorial from BetterTouchTool [here](https://docs.folivora.ai/docs/normal_mice_problems.html). Basically for some mice (like Logitech ones) using the settings application they come with you can map default button actions to clicks and in doing so set a button number and use it as normal.

This works for my Logitech Performance MX mouse.

Comment: This is only thing that worked for me. Basically my mouse is emulating keyboard shortcut for back/forward action, but only in IntellIJ.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a very similar problem and wanted to share my findings.  I just bought a new Logitech M705 mouse.  Within intelli-j the scroll right and scroll left buttons do not work.  The forward and backward buttons also do not work.

I typically run intelli-j as administrator because I need higher privileges to run various tomcat services.  When logging in as that user (rather than right clicking and selecting run as admin) all the buttons work!  Also, when running as my normal user all the buttons work.

Also very curious is that I have an older generation Logitech mouse (same model, M705).  This mouse has no problems with the scroll buttons and forward-back.

My solution for now is to use intelli-j as the user I am logged in as.

Answer (score -1):

You can add mouse shortcuts, just click on an action in keymap and add mouse shortcut.

Alternatively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> brings up switcher, which may be less clicks to navigate.

Comment: Less than one click? =)